# Group items by month and by date

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I want to group my data entries first by month (example: January 2014, Febraruary 2014). This is no problem, but now I have sometimes more than one entry of each day and so I have to group the data another time by date.

Here is an example:

```
var lst = [{02/01/2014, 5}, {02/01/2014, 6}, {02/01/2014, 3}, {01/01/2014, 5}, {01/02/2014, 5}]
```

==> group by month (february, january)

```
[{02/01/2014, 5}, {02/01/2014, 6}, {02/01/2014, 3}], [{01/01/2014, 5}, {01/02/2014, 5}]
```

==> group by day (1. february, 1. january, 2. january)

[{02/01/2014, 4.67}], [{01/01/2014, 5}], [{01/02/2014, 5}]

Here is the code for my KeyedList:

```
public class KeyedList<TKey, TItem> : List<TItem>
{
    public TKey Key { protected set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Items { protected set; get; }

    public KeyedList(TKey key, IEnumerable<TItem> items) : base(items)
    {
        Key = key;
        Items = items;
    }

    public KeyedList(IGrouping<TKey, TItem> grouping)
        : base(grouping)
    {
        Key = grouping.Key;
        Items = grouping;
    }
}
```

For me it is possible to group the values by month:

```
var groupedItems = from item in MyItems
                   orderby Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date) descending,
                   group item by Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date).ToString("MMMM) into items
                   select new KeyedList<string, MyDataType>(items);
```

But how can I do a second grouping to group the days. Thanks.

Comment: Well, but I need two groupings. One grouping by month and another grouping by day. If I'm using directly '''group item by item.Date into items''' than I have only one grouping.

Comment: Your example doesn't have enough dates to make clear what you mean. If you want to collect your results in `KeyedList` one grouping should be enough (by day only?).

Comment: Well. I want to use a first grouping by month. I have a LongListSelector with Header and JumpList Style to move between the months. In this month grouping I want to combine entries from the same day to a single entry. So there was a second grouping by day within the grouping by month.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to organize your results (where this `KeyedList` start playing a role) but this should basically do what you want:

```
from item in MyItems
group item by new { item.Date.Year, item.Date.Month } into monthGroup
select new { monthGroup.Key, 
             Days = from d in monthGroups
                    group d by d.Date.Day into dayGroup
                    select new { d.Key, dayGroup }
           }
```

I use `item.Date`, assuming that you'll be able to build a list of objects with parsed dates first, in stead of the far less efficient multiple parsing in the query itself.

By the way, notice that your `KeyedList` is almost the same as an `IGrouping`. Maybe you can do without.

Comment: I can use your code, but I have a last question. If I want to use an ItemTemplate in my LongListSelector and I have a field called MyText within my class MyItems. How can I use a DataBinding to display MyText?

Comment: There should be something like DisplayValue or DisplayMember in the UI component you use. But if you can't figure it out you better ask a new question with the appropriate details, like type of UI (WPF?) and the exact shape of your data.